# role of $a$ in Hoeffding's Inequality

Tags: probability, inequality

In the book [High-Dimensional Probability](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html), by Roman Vershynin, the Hoeffding's Inequality is stated as the following:

Let $X_1,...,X_N$ be independent symmetric Bernoulli random variables (e.i $P(X=-1)=P(X=1)=1/2$), and let $a = (a_1,...,a_N) \in \mathbb R^N$. Then, for any $t \geq 0$, we have
$$
P\left(\sum^N_{i=1}a_i X_i \geq t \right) \leq e^{\frac{-t^2}{2||a||_2^2}}
$$

My question is what is the role of $a_i$ here?

Normally the general form  of  Hoeffing inequality involve with a range $[a,b]$.

How this form (with $a_i$) of Hoeffding inequality is derived?

Original Theorem and partial proof shown below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: His book has a proof Theorem 2.2.2

Comment: @RishiSonthalia Yeah, I have check that, but it didn't mention anything relate to $a_i$. I will paste the proof later

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't mention anything related to $a_i$"? As far as I can see, the proof does take $a_i$ into account.

Comment: @md5 I mean it didn't state the role of $a_i$, $X_i$ being a random variable and $a$ is a constant associate with $X_i$. I would like to know in what case we can apply summation with $a$. Why it appear in the equation. How's the equation with $a$ derived from? Take the coin toss example, what value should we set for $a$.

Comment: You can choose $a$ to be whatever you like, as the statement is true for all $a$. If you're for example interested in the number of heads in the coin toss experiment, setting $a_i=1$ makes sense.